# Parse /var/email/username file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sendmail

For some reason I need to fetch emails from /var/mail/username file.  It seems like an append only file.

My question is, is it safe to parse the content of the /var/email/username file depending on the first line `From username@host  Mon Jun 20 16:50:15 2011`? What if the similar pattern found inside the email body?

Furthermore, is there any opensource ruby script available for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that seems like more or less the right way to parse the [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format - from a quick scan of the [RFC specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155):

> The structure of the separator lines
> vary across implementations, but
> usually contain the exact character
> sequence of "From", followed by a
> single Space character (0x20), an
> email address of some kind, another
> Space character, a timestamp sequence
> of some kind, and an end-of-    line
> marker.

And...

> Many implementations are also known
> to escape message body lines that
> begin with the character sequence of
> "From ", so as to prevent    confusion
> with overly-liberal parsers that do
> not search for full    separator
> lines.  In the common case, a leading
> Greater-Than symbol    (0x3E) is used
> for this purpose (with "From "
> becoming ">From ").    However, other
> implementations are known not to
> escape such lines    unless they are
> immediately preceded by a blank line
> or if they also    appear to contain
> an email address and a timestamp.
> Other    implementations are also
> known to perform secondary escapes
> against    these lines if they are
> already escaped or quoted, while
> others    ignore these mechanisms
> altogether.

**Update:**
There's also this: https://github.com/meh/ruby-mbox